# Iterating object manipulation or altering multiple objects at once

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Is the best way of doing what i'm doing? `goodThingX`, `badThingX` and `nothin` are UILabels.

```
NSString *todayNothing = [[todayArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey: @"nothing"];
if (todayNothing!=NULL) {
    goodThing1.hidden = YES;
    goodThing2.hidden = YES;
    goodThing3.hidden = YES;
    badThing1.hidden = YES;
    badThing2.hidden = YES;
    badThing3.hidden = YES;
    nothing.text = todayNothing;
    nothing.hidden = NO;
} else {
    goodThing1.hidden = NO;
    goodThing2.hidden = NO;
    goodThing3.hidden = NO;
    badThing1.hidden = NO;
    badThing2.hidden = NO;
    badThing3.hidden = NO;
    nothing.hidden = YES;
}
```

i.e. When the the `todayNothing` has some text, I want to hide 6 labels, and display the `nothing` label, else the opposite. I woudn't have bothered to optimize this, but probably there are going to be more labels than the 6 right now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place them all in an array at `init` or `awakeFromNib` or similar making it easier to iterate over later.

```
@class MyThing {

   UIView *theThings[NUM_THINGS]; // ...or use an NSArray if you like that

}
@end

- (id)init // maybe awakeFromNib would be a better place for UI elements
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    theThings[0] = goodThing1;
    theThings[1] = goodThing2;
    theThings[2] = goodThing3;
    :
  }
  return self;
}
```

...and then later you use a loop like this

```
for (int i=0; i<NUM_THINGS; i++)
  theThings[i].hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I'm using NSArray instead of `UIView *theThings[NUM_THINGS];` and i'm having problems iterating over the loop, i'm trying `[theThings  objectAtIndex:1];` Am i doing it right?

Comment: Use fast enumeration (for-in loop) for `NSArray`!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have something known as "boolean variable".

```
NSString *todayNothing = [[todayArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey: @"nothing"];
BOOL todayNothing_has_something = (todayNothing!=nil); // YES if todayNothing!=nil, NO otherwise
goodThing1.hidden = todayNothing_has_something;
goodThing2.hidden = todayNothing_has_something;
goodThing3.hidden = todayNothing_has_something;
badThing1.hidden = todayNothing_has_something;
badThing2.hidden = todayNothing_has_something;
badThing3.hidden = todayNothing_has_something;
if (todayNothing)
  nothing.text = todayNothing;
nothing.hidden = ! todayNothing_has_something;
```

Second, it's better to use an array or `NSArray` to store all the `good`- and `badThing`s. (See epatel's answer.)

Comment: This brings down the code length by half, so i'm going to use this for now. Meanwhile I'm trying to change epatel's code for NSArray..